# Stochastic Heat Equation: Violated Conservation Law?

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

Solution of stochastic heat equation $u_t=\frac{1}{2}u_{xx}+dW$ with initial condition $u(x,0)=\delta_{x_0}$ is proven to be
$$u(x,t)=\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}G((t-s,x-y)dW(s,y)$$
where $G$ is the fundamental solution of non-stochastic heat equation. It seems to me that with space time white noise the conservation is violated. i.e. $u(x,t)$ is not a time-varying distribution anymore. I'm wondering if there's any theory that "normalizes" $u(x,t)$ so that we can associate it with a distribution-valued process. i.e. $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}u(x,t)dx=1$$

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You wrote an equation with a source, so there is no conservation by any means. What exactly is violated?

Comment: @zhoraster Hi, I'm wondering if there is a distribution-valued process associated with this measured-valued one

Comment: This is impossible and quite nonsense, since your system is not conservative due to the random source.

Comment: By the way, the solution you wrote is incorrect; it corresponds to the zero initial condition.